# Можно ли объеденить несколько полей формы в одну группу-объект?

Tags: html, reactjs, ant-design

Всем привет. Делаю один проект(React, ant-design) и возникло желание в форме отделить несколько элементов от других. Дело в том, что в форме есть select, при помощи которого можно выбрать несколько видов товара(Games, Books). В ответ на это появляются аккордеоны, в которых так же содержаться различные поля ввода. И, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при сабмите формы эти данные выводились в виде:

```
{
    name: ...,
    description: ...,
    Books: {
        height: ...,
        width: ...,
    },
    Games: {
        height: ...,
        width: ...,
    },
}
```

На данный момент это выглядит так:

```
{
    name: ...,
    description: ...,
    height/Books: ...,
    width/Books: ...,
    height/Games: ...,
    width/Games: ...,
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]